# Why my scf calculation with 30*30*30 k-points grid is stuck in the same line for more than 6 hours?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, high-performance-computing, optical-properties

I'm running a scf Quantum ESPRESSO calculation on a cluster to get the optical properties of my material. I noticed that the output file is stuck in the same line for more than 6 hours even though that the calculation is still running. The calculation  is stuck in those lines:

```
....
     Dynamical RAM for                qrad:   3.80 MB

     Dynamical RAM for          rho,v,vnew:   0.57 MB

     Dynamical RAM for               rhoin:   0.19 MB

     Dynamical RAM for            rho*nmix:   1.02 MB

     Dynamical RAM for           G-vectors:   0.25 MB

     Dynamical RAM for          h,s,v(r/c):   0.01 MB

     Dynamical RAM for          <psi|beta>:   0.02 MB

     Dynamical RAM for                 psi:   0.20 MB
     Dynamical RAM for      wfcinit/wfcrot:   0.23 MB

     Estimated static dynamical RAM per process >   3.02 GB

     Estimated max dynamical RAM per process >       3.03 GB

     Estimated total dynamical RAM >      60.52 GB

     Initial potential from superposition of free atoms

     starting charge   35.99975, renormalised to   36.00000
 --- in v_hubbard ---
Hubbard energy    0.0000
 -------
     Number of +U iterations with fixed ns =  0
     Starting occupations:
 --- enter write_ns ---

 --- enter write_ns ---
 LDA+U parameters:
U( 1)     =  5.20000000
atom    1   Tr[ns(na)] =  10.00000
    eigenvalues:
  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000
    eigenvectors:
  1.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
  0.000  1.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
  0.000  0.000  1.000  0.000  0.000
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000  0.000
  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
    occupations:
  1.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
  0.000  1.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
  0.000  0.000  1.000  0.000  0.000
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000  0.000
  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
N of occupied +U levels =   10.000000
 --- exit write_ns ---
 Atomic wfc used for LDA+U Projector are orthogonalized
     Starting wfcs are   19 randomized atomic wfcs +   17 random wfcs
```

I'm not very good at reading the output files but I think it's maybe because of that: `Estimated total dynamical RAM > 60.52 GB` because in my case I used this to launch my calculation:`#SBATCH --mem=10G`.

Does that mean that I should have at least 60.52G RAM in my machine so that the calculation can be done? Or there might be another reason for this issue?

Comment: I cannot recall exactly where but P. Giannozzi once said (probably in the QE user forum) that if the allotted RAM is less than the Estimated total dynamical RAM, then the calculation will run forever. And if I recall correctly, you were working with a large supercell. Do you really need a k-grid of size 30*30*30?

Comment: did the comment help? Are you still looking for an answer?